# How to use Mathematica Online?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, mathematica-online

I am a registered Mathematica user (through my institution). Still Mathematica will ask me to sign up for free trial or to buy Mathematica when I try to upload a document on the cloud so that to use Mathematica Online. Does anyone know how exactly this new feature work?

Comment: This is really a question about what your particular license includes and how to access it.  Such questions are off topic here and should be directed to [Wolfram Support](http://support.wolfram.com/) instead. Not all Mathematica licenses include access to Mathematica Online.